# Weird Inequality I Found in Notes

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, inequality

$$\left\|\sum_{n=0}^{N} f_{n} \right\|^{2} \leq \left(\sum_{n=0}^{N} \|f_{n}\| \right)^{2} \leq \left(\sum_{n=0}^{N} \|f_{n}\|^{2} \right)^{2}$$

The second part of this inequality has to be wrong, right? If the values for each $\|f_{n}\|$ are sufficiently small, then
$$
\left(\sum_{n=0}^{N} \|f_{n}\| \right)^{2} > \left(\sum_{n=0}^{N} \|f_{n}\|^{2} \right)^{2}$$
or am I missing something?

Comment: We seem to be missing something: are there any restrictions on $\|f_n\|$?

Comment: It is just in a general inner product space. I get the first one from the triangle inequality but as I pointed out, I'm quite certain the second piece doesn't hold in general.

Comment: No, I meant the number $\|f_n\|$. I know for sure it's non-negative, but you are probably missing a restriction such at $\|f_n\| > 1$ that would make the above true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It suffices to prove that

$$\ \sum_{n=0}^{N} \|f_{n}\|  \leq \sum_{n=0}^{N} \|f_{n}\|^{2} $$

is wrong.

If it were true, we could have in particular (think for example to the coefficients of Fourier series of the odd function defined by $y=\pi/2-x$ on $[0,2 \pi]$):

$$\tag{1}\sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{1}{n} \leq \sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{1}{n^2}$$

which is evidently erroneous from $N=2$.

For other analog cases,  a more general argument for falsifying (1) is as follows: if $N \rightarrow \infty$,

- the LHS of (1) would constitute a divergent series (harmonic), whereas
- its RHS is a classical convergent Riemann series.

Contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

The inequality cannot hold due to simple scaling reasons. The left-hand side scales linearly w.r.t. the norms of $f_n$ and the right-hand side scales quadratically.

In fact: Suppose that
$$\sum_{n = 0}^N \| f_n \| \le \sum_{n = 0}^N \|f_n\|^2
$$
holds true. Now, let $\alpha > 0$ be given and replace $f_n$ by $\alpha f_n$. This implies
$$\sum_{n = 0}^N \| f_n \| \le \alpha \, \sum_{n = 0}^N \|f_n\|^2
$$
for all $\alpha > 0$. Hence,
$$\sum_{n = 0}^N \| f_n \| \le 0 \qquad \forall \{f_n\}_{n=0}^N$$
and this is only true in my favorite Banach space $\{0\}$.